# ReportViewer and dynamically created dataSet

Tags: c#, report-viewer2010

I saw that the ReportViewer object can get its data from a class or a dataset.
If I use the dataset method I need to create a XSD file that the report will know.
Is there a way to avoid creating this XSD file but still use datasets?

Answer (score 0):

Try using non-typed DataSet in your code on the fly. Create it, fill it and then set it as datasource. 
like following code :

```
SqlCommand mySelectCommand = New SqlCommand("select * from customers", myConnection);
SqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(mySelectCommand);

DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet,"Customers");
```

Use your `myDataSet` wherever you want.

Comment: But how will the report know which value belongs to which item?

Comment: What do you mean ? when set its datasource report will use Customers table.

Comment: Yes, but I use in my report the tablix, a textbox or maybe even two tablixes. How will the report know where to put the values?

Comment: You have to design your Report with specified table, then as I told before it knows what value should insert where.

Comment: Look, have you designed your Report? If yes, you added your table's fields to your Report. Each field has a unique name Report uses these names to bind its value with field's value in DataSource.